# R: reorganizing sublists

Tags: r, list

```
mylist <- list(result.1 = list(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                       3L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
                       6L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
                       4L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 4L), 
                     c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                   4L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 
                                                                   10L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                                                   3L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 
                                                                   8L), 
                     c(2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                          2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
                                                                          6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                          6L, 6L, 4L, 6L)),

     result.2 = list(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                       4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
                       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                       10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), c(6L, 
                                                                            6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
                                                                            5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                                            6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 
                                                                            6L, 10L, 6L, 8L), c(1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 
                                                                                                6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 
                                                                                                10L, 10L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 10L, 
                                                                                                1L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L)))
```

I have a list called `mylist` that looks like the following.

```
> mylist
$result.1
$result.1[[1]]
 [1]  3  3  3  3  3  3  7  3  3  3  3 10  3  3  3  3 10  6  4  6  4 10  4  6  6  6 10  8  6  4  8
[32] 10  3  4  3 10  6  4  6  6  4 10  2  4  2  4  2  8  8  4

$result.1[[2]]
 [1]  3  3  4  4  3  4 10  3 10  4  4 10 10 10 10  4 10 10  4 10 10  4  4  4  4  4  3  4  4  1  4
[32]  3  4  1  3  3 10  4  1  4  4 10  4  4  4  4  8  8  4  8

$result.1[[3]]
 [1] 2 2 2 7 4 2 7 2 2 4 4 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 6 1 4 1 6 1 4 6 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6
[48] 6 4 6


$result.2
$result.2[[1]]
 [1]  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  7  7  7  7  7  4  4  5  7  5  7  4  5  7  7  7  7  7  7  4
[32]  7  7  4  7  4  4  3  4  4 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

$result.2[[2]]
 [1]  6  6  6  1  6  1  6  1  6  1  7  7  7  5  7  5  5  5  7  7  8  7  4  7  7  7  7  6  6  6  6
[32]  6  6  4  6  4  6  6  4  6  4  7  7  6  7  6  6 10  6  8

$result.2[[3]]
 [1]  1  4  1  6  9  6  1  6  1  6  6  6  6  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  5  6 10  1 10 10  1  7  6  6  4
[32]  7 10  1 10  1 10  1 10  4 10  7 10 10  4  4  6  4  4  6
```

It contains two `result`s. Within each `result`, I have 3 sublists. I want to reorganize them in the following way:

```
> new_mylist
[[1]]
result.1 3  3  3  3  3  3  7  3  3  3  3 10 ...
result.2 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  7 ...

[[2]]
result.1 3  3  4  4  3  4 10  3 10  4  4 10 ...
result.2 6  6  6  1  6  1  6  1  6  1  7  7 ...

[[3]]
result.1 2 2 2 7 4 2 7 2 2 4 4 2 2 2 2 4 4 ...
result.2 1  4  1  6  9  6  1  6  1  6  6  6  ...
```

I would like `new_mylist` to contain 3 sublists. Within each sublist, I'm storing the vector from `result.1` and `result.2`. Is there a quick and generalizing way to reorganize lists this way?

Comment: Can I assume that the the vectors inside the `new_mylist` are `list` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be `transpose` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
mylist %>%
   transpose
```

If we need a tibble or data.frame

```
mylist %>% 
   transpose %>% 
   map(as_tibble)
```

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to have a `data.frame` within each sublist of `new_mylist` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapply in base R:

```
mapply(list, mylist$result.1, mylist$result.2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Or more generically (if you have more than 2 results in the list or with arbitrary names for example):

```
do.call(function(...) mapply(list, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE), mylist)
```